# Hide or show mutliple Divs in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a component in my ReactJS app with a Button and a div. My goal is to press the button and show/hide the div, which currently works. But I will re-use the component so I will have multiple Buttons and divs. But I always only want one div to show.

If I press a button, hide all the divs from the same component and show the div from the button I just pressed, otherwise if the button I just pressed div is open hide it. It work the same as Bootstrap's dropdown button, but I prefer not to use Bootstrap's dropdown as I would like to create my own custom button.

I import the below Hide component in my App.js file. It works by hiding or showing the div, but would like to hide all other open div's apart from the button I currently pressed if it is not open yet.

Here is the code I currently have and use my Mycomp twice,

```
function hide () {


        return (
            <div>
                <Mycomp />
                <Mycomp />
            </div>
        );

}


function Mycomp(){
    const[dp, setDp] = useState("none");

    const toggle = () => {
       if (dp === "none"){
        setDp("block")
       }else{
        setDp("none")
       }  
    }

    return(
   <div>
       <button  onClick={toggle}>Test</button>
        <div style={{display: dp}}>{dp}</div>
   </div>

   )
}

export default hide;
```

Comment: You will need to move the state out of the component, either by managing it in the parent component or by using the context api, redux or something similar. The first option will probably be cleaner but that depends on all your `Mycomp`s have the same parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your component this way to get what you want . try to run this code to see the result

```js
function Hide() {
  const [visibleDivIndex, setVisibleDivIndex] = React.useState(0);

  const handleVisibleDiv = id => setVisibleDivIndex(id);

  const divArr = [1, 2, 3]; // just to show haw many component we will use

  return (
    <div>
      {divArr.map((item, index) => (
        <Mycomp
          key={index}
          id={index}
          visibleDivIndex={visibleDivIndex}
          handleVisibleDiv={handleVisibleDiv}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Mycomp({ id, visibleDivIndex, handleVisibleDiv }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={e => handleVisibleDiv(id)}>Test</button>
      <div style={{ display: id === visibleDivIndex ? "block" : "none" }}>
        My Div Content
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Hide />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea would be to move the state up to the container.

```
function Hide() {

    const defaultDisplay = () => Array.from({length: 2}).fill(false);
    const [displays, setDisplays] = useState(defaultDisplay());

    function onClick(id) {
        const temp = defaultDisplay();
        temp[id] = true;
        setDisplays(temp);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                displays.map((display, i) => {
                    return <Mycomp display={display} id={i} onClick={onClick} />;
                }
            }
        </div>
    );
}

function Mycomp({display, id, onClick}) {
    const[dp, setDp] = useState(display);

    useEffect(() => {
        setDp(display ? 'block' : 'none');
    }, [display]);

    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => onClick(id)}>Test</button>
            <div style={{display: dp}}>{dp}</div>
        </div>
   )
}

export default Hide;
```